# How, in EF core, to check if a navigation property is set the most efficient way

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following model

```
public class Asset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssetMetric> Metrics { get; set; }
}

public class AssetMetric
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Whatever { get; set; }
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Metrics")]
    public Asset Asset { get; set; }
}
```

I want to load a list of assets and check at the same time if some AssetMetric are set for each of them.

I could to something like that

```
var summary =  await _dbContext.Assets.Include(x=>x.Metrics).Select(x=>new AssetSummary()
{
    Name = x.Name,
    HasMetrics = x.Metrics.Any(),
}).ToListAsync();
```

However, that mean that I will load all children entities just to check if they exist. I was wondering if a more efficient way to do that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have written effective query. `Include` after `Select` will be ignored and only needed data should be returned. The same query without `Include`:

```cs
var summary =  await _dbContext.Assets
    .Select(x => new AssetSummary()
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        HasMetrics = x.Metrics.Any(),
    }).ToListAsync();
```

If you are worrying about performance, check generated SQL.